# SalesforceObject.search/get not working together? Python / Simple-salesforce

Tags: python, rest, salesforce, soql, force.com

Heres what I'm trying to do:
First of all, I want every entry in Account. After that, I want to use get on them to get the whole thing. However, I get an error message. I do the following:

```
   accIdArr = sf.search("FIND {Account}")
   print accIdArr
   for i in accIdArr:
      print i["Id"]
      accDataArr = sf.Account.get(i["Id"])
   print accDataArr
```

However, I get this error message:

simple_salesforce.api.SalesforceResourceNotFound: Resource Account Not Found. Response content: [{u'errorCode': u'NOT_FOUND', u'message': u'The requested resource does not exist'}]

I then tried to use sf.Account.get('CopyAndPastedId') with the Id that got printed before I get the error, eg i["Id"].
Well, that doesnt work either and gives the same error. So I thought about Account not existing, however sf.Account.metadata() works fine and gives the expected data.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason to use SOSL rather than SOQL?

Since you are only requesting the Account Objects, a simple SOQL search will get you what you want.  Try the following:

```
accDataDict = sf.query('SELECT ID, Name, <all other fields you want> FROM Account')
```

The return will be an ordered dictionary of all the Account Objects with the field/values you requested in your query.